EF Core "An Item with the same key has already been added" error while executing stored procedure with non-unique records
I'm facing an issue when executing a stored procedure via EF Core. The stored procedure returns records that are not unique, and I'm encountering the following error:
An Item with the same key has already been added. Key
I have a custom model defined as follows:
public class CustomModel
{
    public int? ReglerObjekt { get; set; }
    public string Typ { get; set; }
    public int StatusNr { get; set; }
    // other properties...
}

In my DbContext, I've configured the model like this:
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomModel>(entity =>
{
    entity.ToTable("CustomModel");

    // Composite key configuration
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.Typ, e.StatusNr });

    // Property configurations
    entity.Property(e => e.ReglerObjekt).IsRequired(false);
    // other property configurations...
});

I'm calling the stored procedure using FromSqlRaw:
Dim locTableContent = dbContext.CustomModel.FromSqlRaw("EXEC sp_xyz @Id, @globalId",
                     New SqlParameter("@Id", obj.Id),
                     New SqlParameter("@globalId", CType(globalId, Integer?))).AsNoTracking().ToList()

What I Have Tried:
Composite Key: I tried adding a composite key in the model configuration to ensure uniqueness based on Id, Typ, and StatusNr, but the error persists.
AsNoTracking: I also tried adding .AsNoTracking() to avoid EF Core tracking issues, but this did not resolve the issue.
HasNoKey : entity.HasNoKey();
Question:
How can I resolve the "An Item with the same key has already been added" error in EF Core when the stored procedure returns non-unique records? Is there a way to handle non-unique records in EF Core without encountering this error? It's really great for your valueable input or solution.

Please format your post, it is very difficult to read. Also, do you have C# or VB.Net here? Or both?

you have a c# tag, but dim looks more like vb to me, are you sure your tags are correct ?

So which part of the error message is not clear to you???  You tried to enter item that already exist.

HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.Typ, e.StatusNr }) means that the combination of these three values must be unique, but you've said your records are not unique.

@GuidoG : It's combination of VB and C#. EF Core project is C# where we are defining DBContext and DBSet and mapping. In VB project we are creating the Instance of DBContext and using that. We are upgrading the application LinqToSQL to EF Core.

@StriplingWarrior : If combind three of field's value then it's Unique. otherwise two of field's Value are same in the result set. So that's why I have made three combination.

Eric :  Dim locTableContent = dbContext.Xyz.FromSqlRaw("EXEC sp_xyz @Id, @globalId",New SqlParameter("@Id",obj.Id),New SqlParameter("@globalId", CType(globalId, Integer?))) .AsNoTracking().ToList() at this line I am getting error like "An Item with the same key has already been added. key"

to EF ? You mean downgrading then :)

If you have a need to read data rows, whether from a table or generated data that includes completely non-unique rows then you honestly should use something other than EF to read those rows. You can use HasNoKey with either a table or view, so you might need to introduce a view for this to work within EF. There are a number of rules when you use HasNoKey, most notably you cannot use EF to update, insert, or delete rows. From my own tests it also means that entities defined with HasNoKey can have navigation properties "out", meaning they can contain navigation properties pointing at other related entities, but they cannot appear to have navigation properties back. 
Edit: Just had a chance to test this with a Stored Proc and the table/view requirement is not needed. I had assumed/recalled that EF would want to default mapping each entity to a table or view prior to allowing a DbSet, but that is not the case. The following should work without needing a table or a view. If you have a table for CustomModel in the DB, ensure it does not have a PK or any unique constraints set.
modelBuilder.Entity<CustomModel>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasNoKey();
});

That's it, no table or view defined. Alternatively you can just mark the entity class with the [Keyless] attribute.
With the testing I think I was able to reproduce your issue, and it is caused by the way EF is likely parsing the data your stored procedure is returning.
For example if you are querying data from two tables, say a Students table and a StudentClasses table, where both tables have a StudentId column. Doing something like:
SELECT * 
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN StudentClasses sc ON s.StudentId = sc.StudentId
// WHERE, GROUP BY, etc. whatever 

that gets returned by the Stored Proc, this will be returning both [s].StudentId and [sc].StudentId. When the reader goes to inspect and populate the entity/DTO based on the Stored Proc results it encounters the duplicate "StudentId" column name and throws the error you are seeing. In a normal eager-loading scenario when we use .Include(s => s.StudentClasses) EF would be doing just this and would work out which columns go into the Student entity vs. StudentClass. Even if we wanted to write a proc that returned the Student and StudentClasses we cannot use Include() with the ExecuteSQLRaw() and without it, EF does not want to try and iterate through to populate related entities.
If we have a query executing sp_GetStudents intending to populate a Student entity then we need to ensure that the stored procedure does not return any duplicate column names from related tables in the query:
SELECT s.* 
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN StudentClasses sc ON s.StudentId = sc.StudentId
// WHERE, GROUP BY, etc. whatever 

If we do need duplicate columns from tables to use as part of the query then alias them. for instance if our grouping or conditional code must use a column from Table A and Table B in the logic but we are just populating table A to return, then alias the column from table B. For example:
SELECT a.Id, a.Name, b.Name AS BName
FROM TableA a
INNER JOIN TableB b ON a.Id = b.AId
// WHERE/Group/Etc that depends on b.Name.

If we had left both a.Name and b.Name in the SELECT, the SQL logic would differentiate them by table alias (a/b) but EF composing the model expecting a "Name" column would get two values. Aliasing b.Name as "BName" would see EF ignore it when populating a TableA entity. The caveat of loading an entity/DTO with a Stored Proc is that you cannot eager load related entities. They will either require lazy loading, explicit loading after the fact, or pre-loading /w change tracker association.

I don't want update currently just want to get the records which is returned by SP. I am not sure on this how to performed : entity.ToView("vw_CustomModels")
.HasNoKey();

I had a bit of time this morning to give it a test and revised the answer with a probable explanation for the error you are still seeing even if using HasNoKey(). The ToTable()/ToView() is not required which I verified with my tests and removed that from the answer.

Not working as suggested I haved used [Keyless] attribute in the class. but not working. I have try this one also  Dim locTableContent = dbContext.CustomModel.FromSqlRaw("EXEC sp_xyz @Id, @globalId",
New SqlParameter("@Id", obj.Id),
New SqlParameter("@globalId", CType(globalId, Integer?))).AsEnumerable()
.GroupBy(Function(x) New With {x.ObjektID, x.ReglerObjektTyp, x.StatusNr})
.Select(Function(g) g.First()) ' Select the first occurrence
.ToList() Please suggest any know how to fix it

You need to look at the stored procedure "sp_xyz" and what columns it returns. There can be no duplicate named columns otherwise you will get the item with same key error. It's not complaining about duplicate rows, but duplicate columns in the SQL the stored procedure is returning. Nothing you change on the EF/code side will fix that.

The problem got resolved due to a stored procedure which didn’t have have an alias name. I have set the alias and it got resolved.
Original Stored Procedure:
SELECT      
   Objekt.[Objekt]      
 , Objekt.[ObjektTyp]      
 , ISNULL(Objekt.[ObjektID], '')   
 , Objekt.[StatusNr]      
 , ISNULL(Begriff.[BegriffLandSpr], '-') 

New Stored Procedure:
SELECT      
   Objekt.[Objekt]      
 , Objekt.[ObjektTyp]      
 , ISNULL(Objekt.[ObjektID], '')  AS [ObjektID]   
 , Objekt.[StatusNr]      
 , ISNULL(Begriff.[BegriffLandSpr], '-')  AS  [BegriffLandSpr] 

